# input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I have defined a dataTable Like this

```
DataTable dtFinal = new DataTable();
dtFinal.Columns.Add("AVNR", typeof(int));
dtFinal.Columns.Add("Substation", typeof(string));
dtFinal.Columns.Add("ColumnTitle", typeof(string));
dtFinal.Columns.Add("S6_NAME", typeof(string));
dtFinal.Columns.Add("Voltage", typeof(string));
dtFinal.Columns.Add("Wert", typeof(decimal));
```

and I make a join between two tables to have a result set

```
  var results = from table1 in dtTimeListTable.AsEnumerable()
                join table2 in readyDataTable.AsEnumerable() on (decimal)table1["Avnr"] equals (int)table2["Avnr"]
                select new
                {
                    AVNR = (int)table2["AVNR"],
                    Substation = (string)table2["Substation"],
                    ColumnTitle = (string)table2["ColumnTitle"],
                    S6_NAME = (string)table2["S6_NAME"],
                    Voltage = (string)table2["Voltage"],                                  
                    Wert = (decimal)table1["Wert"]                                   
                 };
```

to fill datatable up I do the following:

```
            dtFinal.Rows.Add(results.ToArray());
```

but I'll get a error liek this

> input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

both datatable have 6 columns, what could be the problem?

Comment: What columns are in your `dtTimeListTable` and the `readyDataTable`?

Comment: Because `result` isn't the anonymous object you are declaring in the `select` clause, it's an `IEnumerable` of that anonymous object.
(Converted to a comment since Tim was faster...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataRowCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRowCollection_Add_System_Object___) is a method to add a single `DataRow` but you are trying to add all rows.

You  need a loop:

```
foreach(var x in query)
    dtFinal.Rows.Add(x.AVNR, x.Substation, x.ColumnTitle, x.S6_NAME, x.Voltage, x.Wert);
```

You could build the `object[]` for each `DataRow` also in this way:

```
var joinedRows = from table1 in dtTimeListTable.AsEnumerable()
                 join table2 in readyDataTable.AsEnumerable() on (decimal) table1["Avnr"] equals (int) table2["Avnr"]
                 select new { r1 = table1, r2 = table2 };

foreach (var x in joinedRows)
{
    object[] fields =
    {
        x.r2.Field<int>("AVNR"), x.r2.Field<string>("Substation"), x.r2.Field<string>("ColumnTitle"),
        x.r2.Field<int>("S6_NAME"), x.r2.Field<string>("Voltage"), x.r1.Field<decimal>("Wert"),
    };
    dtFinal.Rows.Add(fields);
}
```